# lists on custom listview are all the same, should be different in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, list, listview

How to display a list on a custom listview that varies like this :

[true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSbsb.png)

Not like this:

[false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wtw7.jpg)

where to see each other, everything is the same?

I created **Daftar.vb** using **User Controls (Windows Forms)** and I created a custom list view using **FlowLayoutPanel** and in it I entered the **Daftar** Toolbox

code :

Daftar.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Daftar1
#Region "Properties"
    Private _title As String
    Private _message As String
    Private _icon As Image
    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Title As String
        Get
            Return _title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _title = value
            judul.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Message As String
        Get
            Return _message
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _message = value
            deskripsi.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Icon As Image
        Get
            Return _icon
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Image)
            _icon = value
            gambar.Image = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
End Class
```

RestaurantApp.vb

```
Public Class RestaurantApp
    Private Sub PopulateItems()
        Dim listItems As Daftar1() = New Daftar1(20) {}
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To listItems.Length - 1
            listItems(i) = New Daftar1()
            listItems(i).Title = "vdsvhd"
            listItems(i).Message = "Penjelasan"
            If i <> 0 Then
                panelDaftar.Controls.Add(listItems(i))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub RestaurantApp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call Me.PopulateItems()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are adding the same data inside of the for loop. The title and the message for each list item index `i` is being set to `vdsvhd` and `Penjelasan`

Comment: I'm still confused by @Anu6is explanation. Can you provide an example of code that meets my expectations?

Comment: It's not clear what confuses you.  Your titles are all the same: `listItems(i).Title = "vdsvhd"`

Comment: Change `listItems(i).Title = "vdsvhd"` to `listItems(i).Title = "vdsvhd" & i.ToString()`. That should give you a hint

Comment: almost! @Anu6is I want to display a list like this : ("Barbeque", "Apple", "Sandwitch", "Bread", ...) not like this ("title1", "title2", "title3", "title4", . ..)

Comment: The change was just to highlight what your issue was. As far as showing your list of titles, where does that list come from? No where in your question did you indicate that you have a list of items that you want to add to the custom listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I search on Stackoverflow and Youtube, I've managed to find the answer. The following is the code for **RestaurantApp.vb** :

```
Public Class RestaurantApp
    Private Sub PopulateItems()
        Dim listItems As Daftar1() = New Daftar1(5) {}
        Dim judul As String() = New String(4) {"Burger", "Sosis", "Nasi", "Pizza", "Ayam"}
        Dim penjelasan As String() = New String(4) {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To listItems.Length - 1
            If i < judul.Length And i < penjelasan.Length Then
                listItems(i) = New Daftar1()
                listItems(i).Title = judul(i)
                listItems(i).Message = penjelasan(i)
                If i <> 0 Then
                    panelDaftar.Controls.Add(listItems(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub RestaurantApp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call Me.PopulateItems()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you @anu6is and Stackoverflow